# Regarding the definitions of time-constructible functions on Wikipedia

Tags: complexity-theory, definitions

I am reading the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_function#cite_note-3) article on time-constructible functions and got confused by its definitions, given as follows:

> There are two different definitions of a time-constructible function. In the first definition, a function $f$ is called time-constructible if there exists a positive integer $n_0$ and Turing machine $M$ which, given a string $1^n$ consisting of $n$ ones, stops after exactly $f(n)$ steps for all $n \ge n_0$. In the second definition, a function $f$ is called time-constructible if there exists a Turing machine $M$ which, given a string $1^n$, outputs the binary representation of $f(n)$ in $\mathcal{O}(f(n))$ time (a unary representation may be used instead, since the two can be interconverted in $\mathcal{O}(f(n))$ time).[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_function#cite_note-3)

1. If I am not mistaken the two definitions are not equivalent: The first one is more strict.
2. I think this definitions are lacking the requirement that $f(n) \ge n$, since the part about converting an unary to a binary representation might not be true as this requires $f(n) \ge n$, i.e. the algorithm needs to be able to read the input, which might not be the case for small enough $f(n)$.

Am I right with this or am I missing something here?

Comment: (It was long ago, so I'm not confident) I think that you are right about 1, but it doesn't matter in applications (s.t. hierarchy theorems). 2 implies that $f(n) = o(n)$ is not time-constructible.